# Por que a vírgula some ao converter um HTML para str no Python?

Tags: html, python, string, pandas, web-scraping

Eu tô extraindo uns dados de uma página utilizando scraping seguindo um tutorial que vi no YouTube. Segue o código:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import  sleep


url = 'https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/como_ccee_atua/precos/preco_horario?_afrLoop=600752069821480&_adf.ctrl-state=hyxt02uk_54#!%40%40%3F_afrLoop%3D600752069821480%26_adf.ctrl-state%3Dhyxt02uk_58'
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)
sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='SUL']//a").click()
sleep(1)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='listaValoresPrecoHorario']")
html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(name='table')
df = pd.read_html(str(table),encoding='UTF-8')[0]
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Porém, como os dados estão sendo convertidos para string, alguns valores estão perdendo a vírgula:

```
>> Hora PLD HORÁRIO (R$/MWh)
>> 0   00:00                18254
>> 1   01:00                17454
>> 2   02:00           MIN 173,01
>> 3   03:00                17318
>> 4   04:00                17330
>> 5   05:00                17380
>> 6   06:00                17619
>> 7   07:00                18226
>> 8   08:00                19117
>> 9   09:00                19476
>> 10  10:00                19777
>> 11  11:00                19425
>> 12  12:00                19244
>> 13  13:00                19426
>> 14  14:00           MAX 200,27
>> 15  15:00                19983
>> 16  16:00                19752
>> 17  17:00                19272
>> 18  18:00                19477
>> 19  19:00                19967
>> 20  20:00                19938
>> 21  21:00                19979
>> 22  22:00                19114
>> 23  23:00                18522
```

Além disso, não estou conseguindo converter os valores para float. Provavelmente por que algumas linhas tem texto e não número. Mas eu queria ao menos recuperar as vírgulas dos números. Como posso fazer isso? Desde já agradeço.

Obs: Note que estranhamente as linhas que tem texto além de número são as que preservam as vírgulas.

Comment: Qual o resultado de print(html_content)?

Comment: E de print(table)?

Comment: Tenho impressão que o problema esta no `pd.read_html`. De acordo com a documentação o parâmetro `thousands` é por padrão ','. Aparentemente `pd.read_html` está convertendo para número a coluna de preços. Por isso quando tem o texto MIN e MAX não é convertido. Documentação https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: Em html_content tem o trecho da tabela em html da página, em table está o mesmo trecho só agora convertido para o tipo bs4.element.Tag. Eduardo Bissi, muito obrigado. Resolveu aqui. Como faço pra deixar seu comentário em evidência?